# Simple Javascript not doing anything, no errors in console

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm writing a simple Javascript form validator, but when I run it, it's not doing anything at all.

```
function submitFunction()
{
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;
  var y = document.forms["myForm"]["pwd"].value;
  if(x == null || x == "" || y == null || y == "")
  {
    alert("Both fields cannot be empty");
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Username" + x + " Password: " + y);
  }
}
```

am I missing something simple?

it is called like this:

```
<div id="register">
<form name='registration' id="registration" onSubmit="return     formValidation()">

Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>

Password:  <input type="password" name="pwd"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: What calls the function?

Comment: Not the problem, but note that you don't need to test for null values because the .value property won't ever return null.

Comment: have you checked for errors in the console?

Comment: I'll add the caller of the function in the question.

Comment: @RyanWerner You aren't calling it in that code. It looks like you're trying to call `formValidation` but not `submitFunction`.

Comment: Why is there a return in the onSubmit attribute?

Comment: @evolutionxbox So the form submission will be prevented if the function returns `false`.

Comment: I've fixed all the simple naming errors. I have checked for errors in the console but I'm not seeing anything, I'll have another look.

Comment: The `onsubmit` attribute expects the function to return `true` or `false` depending on whether the validation is successful. Your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Barmar but shouldn't the function be returning false... Not the attribute...

Comment: @evolutionxbox If you don't use a `return` statement in the attribute, then the return value of the function is ignored.

Comment: Why do people use the attribute anyway? Why not just listen to the submit event?

Comment: @evolutionxbox When you write `onsubmit="code"` it's like writing `form.onsubmit= function() { code; }`

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because they learned from tutorials that were written 20 years ago.

Comment: I've tried everything here but still no joy, no idea what the problem could be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues here: your onSubmit callback is not calling the right function, and your submitFunction is not accessing the right form ID.

This should work as expected:

HTML:

```
<div id="register">
<form name='registration' id="registration" onSubmit="return submitFunction()">

Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>

Password:  <input type="password" name="pwd"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function submitFunction(){

  var x = document.forms["registration"]["username"].value;
  var y = document.forms["registration"]["pwd"].value;
  if(x == null || x == "" || y == null || y == "")
  {
    alert("Both fields cannot be empty");
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Username" + x + " Password: " + y);
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/yOKoaG?editors=1010